# Executing a UpdateByQueryRequest in Elasticsearch Java client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-java-api

I want to run an `update-by-query` call on Elasticsearch. I wrote the code to execute as follows and it works,

```
UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder builder = buildUpdateByQueryRequestBuilder();
builder.get();
```

However, during the code review someone told me to, instead of calling get() on the builder to use `UpdateByQueryRequest` class by invoking `builder.request()` which sorta makes sense.

But the issue is, I don't know how to execute a `UpdateByQueryRequest`. I looked at the online documentation but there doesn't seem to be any documentation on it.

So is `UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder#get()` the way to go or could an `UpdateByQueryRequest` be actually be invoked?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

invoke `builder.get()` directly, this is a block execute, you can use [execute](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/7560101ec73331acb39a042bde6130e59e4bb630/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/ActionRequestBuilder.java) with [ActionListener](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/ActionListener.java) async execute.

maybe you can do it like:

```
builder.execute(new ActionListner<BulkIndexByScrollResponse> {
   void onResponse(Response response) {
   // do something
   }
   void onFailure(Exception e) {
   // do something
   }
}
```